# Can there be external division here?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, contest-math, tangent-line

**Question:**

A curve $y=f(x)$ passes through $(1,1)$ and at $P(x,y),$ tangent cuts the $x$-axis and $y$-axis at $A$ and $B$ respectively such that $BP:AP=3:1$ then

A) $xy'-3y=0$

B) normal at $(1,1)$ is $x+3y=0$

C) curve passes through $(2,1/8)$

D) equation of curve is $xy'+3y=0$

**My Attempt:**

Let the tangent at $P$ is $Y-y=y'(X-x)$, where $y'$ is the slope of the curve at P.

Therefore $A$ is $(-y/y'+x,0)$ and $B$ is $(0,-xy'+y)$

Assuming internal division, I am getting $D$ option.

Assuming external division, I am getting $A$ option.

But as per answer key, option $A$ is not correct.

Why can't we take external division here?